# Cannot get value POST Method RESTFUL Service

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I use RESTful web service in ASP.NET MVC4, When POST method call, parameter[FromBody] is null.
How to fix it?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The client needs to send the value with the following format:

```
=huhu
```